# is there a way to force hadoop job to look into underscore folder?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I have to process a bunch of files in a folder that begins with "_" (underscore).  Is there a way I can force hadoop to look into those folders?  Do I need to write my own FileInputFormat?

Comment: Do you mean that the folders starting with "_" are more than one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to build the list of input files by yourself using for instance `FileSystem.globStatus` then manually add them to the job with `FileInputFormat.addInputPath`. `FileSystem.globStatus` doesn't filter hidden files by default.